# What is the correct way of using `Case` in a select statement when comparing values by using `Like`?

Tags: mysql

I have this query that is not return anything:

```
select
    case when Username like 'participanta%' then
        'Novice'
    when Username like 'participantb%' then
        'Experienced'
    when Username like 'participantc%' then
        'Master'
    end as 'group'
from Users;
```

I just want the values to be "Novice" if the `Username` is like `participanta12`, and so on.

I've also tried this query which just gets rid of the `Username like` after the second and third `when` :

```
select
    case when Username like 'participanta%' then
        'Novice'
    when 'participantb%' then
        'Experienced'
    when 'participantc%' then
        'Master'
    end as 'group'
from Users;
```

Also tried for a single user group:

```
select
    case when Username like 'participanta%' then
        'Novice'
    end as 'group'
from Users;
```

Still does not return anything.

Comment: What does the data in your table look like? Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Your first query should work if you simply change

```
as 'group'
```

to be

```
as `group`
```

Comment: Oddly enough, a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e1dc/3) shows this problem even when using the backtick.

Comment: @Mark Bannister I just tried the back-ticks but it did not work.

Comment: My bad, typo in the fiddle and the [backticks are irrelevant](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c0b9/5).  I would guess that the OP might have a typo somewhere as well ;)

Comment: @icanc: check this SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c0b9/1

Comment: Not sure if this is a MySQL WorkBench problem but in the "response" column it shows that `110 row(s) returned` but nothing is output.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Mark's answer.

You first case statement is correct.
However you're using the `as` construct wrong.

If you want to escape reserved keywords you need to use the backtick `` ` ``, not the quote `'`.

See: [MySQL and CASE WHEN with a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913177/mysql-and-case-when-with-a-range-of-values)

For a similar question.

Comment: The standard quotes seem to work just fine as well - see my comment to @MarkBannister's answer.