# how to combine results of two different queries from one table mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL in phpMyAdmin, I have a table from which I am trying to get the following result as illustrated below:

I have a table Rate structured as follows;

```
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+----------+
| EntryID | RegDate   |  Code | Buying | Selling | Averages |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+----------+
| 1       |2013-11-08 |  USD  | NULL   | NULL    | 0.814    |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+----------+   
| 2       |2013-11-08 |  GBP  | NULL   | NULL    | 0.114    |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+---------+----------+
```

With the primary key as EntryID I am trying to get the output as shown below;

```
+-----------+-------+-------+
| RegDate   |  USD  |  GBP  |
+-----------+-------+-------+
|2013-11-08 | 0.814 | 0.114 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. Maybe trying viewing in text editor like Notepad. Please and Thanks for the responses in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT USD.RegDate, USD.Averages as USD,
GBP.Averages as GBP From
(SELECT RegDate, Averages
From Table1 where Code = 'USD') USD
Inner join
(SELECT RegDate, Averages
From Table1 where Code = 'GBP') GBP
ON USD.RegDate = GBP.RegDate
```

**[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5e05/1)**

Comment: Works great. Think I have a better idea of the Inner Join aswell. Can the same principle be used if I had more fields like CAD, EUR?

Comment: Yes. Same principal can be used as many times.
but, my recommendation goes with @valex's answer as there is no joins.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RegDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code='USD' THEN Averages ELSE 0 END) as USD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code='GBP' THEN Averages ELSE 0 END) as GBP
FROM T
GROUP BY RegDate
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cfd/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `JOIN` the table with itself, use the table once for each currency you need;

```
SELECT usd.RegDate, usd.averages USD, gbp.averages GBP
FROM Table1 usd
JOIN Table1 gbp
  ON usd.regdate = gbp.regdate
 AND usd.code = 'USD'
 AND gbp.code = 'GBP';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c13d/1).

Note that this query assumes that each currency exists exactly once per date to give a good result, if that's not the case, you should add that to your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT EntryID, regDate,
SUM(CASE Code WHEN 'USD' THEN Averages ELSE 0 END) as USD,
SUM(CASE Code WHEN 'GBP' THEN Averages ELSE 0 END) as GBP
FROM TableA
GROUP BY regDate
```

See [Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913177/mysql-and-case-when-with-a-range-of-values)

Comment: Basically the same except that I have `EntryID` which the author indicate should be there. Hopefully by the way you are not implying that I am copying from him. I am working on it separately on a separate tab/browser when I came back I saw his answer which is basically the same as mine but I still continue because of the tiny difference as I've  mentioned earlier. Check also the difference in the way we use `CASE`, there is a minor difference between him and I.

Comment: My correct link by the way should be [this link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf73/1)