# multiple if in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I had SQL a few years ago, but somehow I can't remember how to solve this problem anymore, and since I tried for so long I thought I should just ask here, because I feel like the solution is really simple.

I have a table called players like this:

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
 <tr>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>birthday</td>
  <td>attribute_1</td>
  <td>attribute_2</td>
  <td>value</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Mike</td>
  <td>1992-05-11</td>
  <td>57</td>
  <td>60</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Max</td>
  <td>1980-12-07</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Tom</td>
  <td>1986-02-10</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I now want to add a value to every person based on their attribute 1, 2 and their age like follows:

- If someone is 27 or younger, than attribute_1 should be weighted with 70%, attribute_2 with 30%.
- If someone is older than 27 but younger than 32 than subtract the value 5 to the result from above.
- If someone is older than 31 subtract the value 10 to the result.
- Now if the value would drop to zero or below (because his attributes 1 and 2 are below 10 and he is older than 32 for example) than set the value to 2.

I already fail with one if-clause, so I don't really now what to change here:

```
SELECT IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW() <= 27)
SET value = ((attribute_1/100*70) + (attribute_2/100*30))
ELSE set value = 2;
```

Any idea where my fault is? Thanks in advance!

New Query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
       END AS marktwert
FROM _spieler;
```

this is with the actual values, geburtstag is birthday, w_staerke attribute_1, w_technik attribut_2 "marktwert" is value and _spieler the players table

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2913191/785663) looks like it might help you with the `CASE .. WHEN` construct?

Comment: I'm not sure how to actually transform this for my problem properly because I don't know where the "(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()" statement is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use MySQL's [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((attribute_1/100*70) + (attribute_2/100*30))
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()) <= 31 THEN .... 
       END AS value
FROM ....;
```

Comment: This seems like the way, however, after SELECT starting from CASE phpMyAdmin underlines everything in red. Adding a bracket after SELECT helps, but I still get an error when I try to execute the command

Comment: you have to add an `END` after the last `THEN` clause

Comment: I don't think sending the user down the path of constructing "prepared statements" is the right path for a 'simple solution'

Comment: there's no prepared statement in my solution - it's just a simple `SELECT` statement

Comment: @TudorConstantin You are right.  Nevermind.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: The missing 'FROM' was throwing me - looking more and more like a prepared statement.  Now it looks more like a SELECT statement.

Comment: yeah, I was in a hurry and forgot to delete the rest of the original query

Comment: I added both END and FROM _players at the end now, but I still get the following error (everything underlined red) when executing: An Expression was expected. (near "CASE" at position 7). It's probably just a stupid mistake from my side especially considering I had SQL and databases in college, but it somehow just won't click for me

Comment: I edited to add an alias to the whole CASE...maybe that was missing?

Comment: added it aswell but still the same unfortunately

Comment: please edit your question and add the whole query there, so we can see it

Comment: done. I added the actual names of the columns and table aswell, might help finding the error

Comment: can you connect to the MySQL server through a console and execute the query there? it might be phpMyAdmin that throws the error you get? 
Or, try and select another column, right before the CASE, like SELECT geburtstag, CASE ...

Comment: Yep, seems like it's a phpMyAdmin error, just writing SELECT CASE gives me an error instantly. Selecting another column showed the same error. Any workarrounds?

Comment: try and put the whole CASE ... THEN ... END statement on a single line

Comment: Still the same. I might have to use a different one than phpMyAdmin I guess

Comment: try and reduce the whole CASE ... THEN ... END expression to something really simple and see if that works and then add complexity to it.
See if this works in phpMyAdmin for example: SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1980-01-01', NOW()) <= 27 THEN 1 else 0 END;

Comment: Now even the query from above worked, I don't know why but I'm glad it did, thanks! However, that query only shows the results, I wanted to actually change the value in the column "marktwert" permanently. That's why I thought I need Set for that

Comment: For the update part my recommendation is to create another question (after you accept my solution if it helped you :) ), because this gets clunky.

Comment: Of course it did, done, and thanks again! Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726175/sql-updating-a-column

Comment: it was my pleasure to help - let me see if I can help with the other one :)

Comment: well, I rewrote your question, because people jumped on you and robbed you of your hard earned early points :))

Comment: I wrote in the question body the UPDATE statement .... that might work out of the box

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()) <= 27,
          (attribute_1/100*70) + (attribute_2/100*30),
          2
         );
FROM <table name goes here>
```

You are using the 'IF()' **function** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

It takes three parameters - condition, true, false:

(not to be confused with the IF statement when constructing Prepared Statements https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html )

Also, the 'SET' statement is probably not what you want:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html

But if you do want to set user defined variables:

```
SET @value =  IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()) <= 27,
                (attribute_1/100*70) + (attribute_2/100*30),
              2
              );


SELECT @value;

+--------------+
| @value       |
+--------------+
| 30.000000000 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And note that 'birthday', 'attribute_1' and 'attribute_2' will be unknown - unless you select them from a table, or make them user defined variables, in which case you need to add the '@' in front.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It kinda helped, but now I'm getting the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'birthday' in 'field list' even though the birthday column is there

Comment: SELECT (stuff above)
FROM (table with birthday, attribute_1, attribute_2 fields)

Comment: Using "multuple if's" is best turned into a CASE statement, as @TudorConstantin shows in his answer

Comment: Alright, seems a bit simpler aswell which is not too bad considering I'm not really into SQL anymore. Still thanks for your help!

Comment: I actually did right when you posted your first solution, all I get is "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." though, not sure if it still counts