# SQL update a calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table which I need to update. The column is computed like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
       END AS marktwert
FROM _spieler;
```

I want to update column on all the records from that table.

Can I use something like

```
UPDATE _spieler SET marktwert = CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
           END;
```

The query seems to be correct, however it sets the value in "marktwert" to zero for every row.

```
CREATE TABLE `_spieler` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vorname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nachname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geburtstag` date NOT NULL,
  `w_staerke` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `w_technik` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `marktwert` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `age` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=535 ;

(1, 'Adam', 'Federici', '1985-01-31', 30, 20, 0, NULL),
(2, 'Ryan', 'Allsop', '1992-06-17', 20, 30, 0, NULL),
(3, 'Tyrone', 'Mings', '1980-03-13', 40, 20, 0, NULL),
(4, 'Joe', 'Bennett', '1990-03-28', 25, 30, 0, NULL),
(5, 'Charlie', 'Daniels', '1986-09-07', 50, 30, 0, NULL);
```

table definition and some sample data

```
UPDATE _spieler 
SET marktwert = CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30)) * 600000 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN (((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30)) * 600000) - 5000000 
WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) > 31 THEN (((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30)) * 600000) - 10000000 END
```

final query added

Comment: are you sure that SO is SQL tutorial?

Comment: Guys, he's new here, I suggested him to create a new question based on the old one. I think he hurried up a little and posted this poorly formulated one. I rewrote it completely in order to add some context. Can you take back your downvotes so he'll not be discouraged to ask for help in the future? :))

Comment: They are right and I apologise for that, really should have taken my time. Even if it's a bit offtopic I just wanted to thank you again Tudor for being so understanding and pacient, this is really rare nowadays

Comment: ok I removed the downvote, now that you edited it at least it has some sense, Saint-Tudor ;)

Comment: @Malgunda no you can't do this because `marktwert` is not a **column** in a table, so there's nothing you can update. `marktwert` is only an **alias** you gave to a resulting field of your previous query. Thus it doesnt physically exists anywhere, how could you update it?

Comment: it actually is a column in a table called _spieler in my database, that first query was the result of a misunderstanding I just realized. The query below seems to be correct, however it sets the value in "marktwert" to zero for every row

Comment: Please provide table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE _spieler`) and sample data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Done. What I was wondering...is it possible to use values from a created alias like above, the "markwert" one, to update a column permanently, even if that alias is not physically there? Because if it is I might solved my problem, however, I don't know if, and if it is, how to use the values in that alias

Comment: "is it possible to use values from a created alias like above ..?" - you can use a VIEW (see the updated answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not calculate any `marktwert` value for players (Spieler) who is older than 31 years (geburtstag = birthday). Your UPDATE statement is trying to write `NULL` into the `marktwert` column, which is defined as `NOT NULL`. And that results in an error.

Solutions:

1) User `ELSE` in your `CASE` statement and set a default value:

```sql
UPDATE _spieler SET marktwert =     CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
        ELSE 0
    END;
```

2) Allow `NULL` value for column `marktwert`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `_spieler` (
  ...
  `marktwert` int(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ...
)
```

3) Use a `WHERE` condition:

```sql
UPDATE _spieler SET marktwert =     CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
    END
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31;
```

Update: You can also remove the `marktwert` column and use a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html) (calculated table) instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `_spieler_view` AS SELECT s.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 27 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geburtstag, NOW()) <= 31 THEN ((w_staerke/100*70) + (w_technik/100*30))
    END AS marktwert_calculated
from _spieler s ;
```

Update 2:

If you use MariaDB you could also use [Virtual (Computed) Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/)

Comment: So me trying to simplify my query actually caused the problem. Thank you very much, finally done :) And of course everyone else who (tried) to help!

Comment: I just realized I get negativ values for `marktwert` in some cases. Is it possible to say that all negativ values should be automaticly changed to a value of 1? Solution 1 worked best actually, thanks for the effort!

Comment: How is a negative value possible? Either `w_staerke` or `w_technik` must be negative. Is that the case?

Comment: Dang, my fault. I now edited the actual query I want to use to the bottom of the post above. I subtract a certain amount of value if a player reaches a certain age, that was the whole point of the CASE usage actually

Comment: With your update it becames an other question. However - i would handle the negative values in your application. Pseudo code: `if marktwert < 0 then marktwert = 1;` - which should be trivial for any programmer. But a solution in SQL would either need a subquery or more complex conditions (SQL is not procedural).

Comment: I tried something similar with SQL but it didn't work, that's probably why then. `UPDATE _spieler SET marktwert IF (marktwert < 0, marktwert = 1, marktwert) `, but again, the value was 0 rather than 1 (which is still better than a negative value). Probably something to do with IF function and statement, but not that important actually